# Printing MySQL data from while loop elsewhere

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I currently have two dropdowns and a div. My aim is to be able to use variables printed in the selected `<option>` of the second dropdown inside the div. As illustrated, I've tried to do this with an array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$items = array();

// converting day into the date of the next time that day occurs

function getDateString($day) {
        if (date("l") == $day) {
            return date("D j M");
        }
        else {
            $date = strtotime("next $day");
            return date("D j M",$date);
        }
    }

// populating the second dropdown

    function getClubs() {
    connect();

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $day = date("l");
    $time = date("G");

    if ($time >= 21) {
        $day = date('l', strtotime($day .' +1 day'));
        }


    if ($day == Monday) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Tuesday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Wednesday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Thursday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Friday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Saturday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY')";
        }

    else if ($day == Sunday) {
        $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')";
        }


        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $items = array();

        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    //          $items[] = array($row['name']);

    $name = $row['name'];
    $day = $row['day'];

// add these two to an array

                array_push($items, $name, $day);

                echo "<option>" . $name . " (" . getDateString($day) . ")</option>";

                }         
        }
    }

// populating div

function printDetails() {

// echo $name (as an example) from the array above

   echo $items[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo "<option>" . $name . " (" . getDateString($day) . ")</option>";
```

to

```
$dropdown .= "<option>" . $name . " (" . getDateString($day) . ")</option>";
```

And then inside your down

```
<select><?=$dropdown;?></select>
```

You are echoing the option tags in your code where it exists in order of the HTML which is being printed. Meaning, you are echoing it outside of select tags. By using the .= you are concatenating the $dropdown variable with the rest of the options in the loop.

At the end of the day, your downdown options will exist in $dropdown, which you can use anywhere on the page, wherever you place it.

ex:

```
<div><?=$dropdown;?></div>
<select><?=$dropdown;?></select>
```

But be aware of the  tags around each item.

Comment: Could you explain what this does? I'm looking for the individual values (name, day, etc) that I can echo inside a div. My next step is to update the div for when a different dropdown selection is made.

Comment: Thanks for your update. What I'm trying to use elsewhere is the current name/day/etc that is selected in the dropdown. So here (http://comfyshoulderrest.com/guestvibe/index.php) it'll be the club that is selected on page load so it can be printed in the thin, dark grey div on the right.